# Can't build keystore: [Private key missing (bad password?)] - SOAPUI

Tags: ssl, soapui

I got a serious problem while making an SSL request to the server with SOAPUI. I am a newbie in SoapUI and maybe I did something wrong while I'm trying to import the certificate into SOAPUI.

My client sends me:

- Root CA
- Intermediate CA
- SSL CA
- Private Key

I am using keytore to generate keystore with password by command

`keytool -genkey -alias soapui -keyalg RSA -keystore soapui.keystore`

And then I tried to export the this keystore with my SSL CA

`keytool -export -alias soapui -file SSL.cer -keystore soapui.keystore`

And then I import this into Keystores in the SoapUI.

However, I got the error

`ERROR:java.security.KeyStoreException: Can't build keystore: [Private key missing (bad password?)]`

I have no idea where am I wrong?

Could anyone please indicate what are the steps I should work on to make the SSL request to SoapUI?

Please help

Thank you.

Comment: I am not sure why your client sends you private key? Are you trying to make a request with client certificate?

Comment: @AlexeyR. Yes, I am trying to make the request with the client certificate, but I don't know how to do this. My client just sent me a bunch of certificates but I don't know what to do with that. Could you please help?

Comment: Looking at the above, it looks like you have been on SmartBears website for the guide.  They have a forum too and it might be worth asking the question there as well.

Comment: If your client has really sent you his private key you both need to start again with some more reliable sources of information. In a Java context I would start with the JSSE Reference Guide, or the Tomcat SSL instructions. Your client has compromised his private key and it must not be used again. But wat you have done so far given the inputs you have makes no sense: not that the inputs make sense either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you need to make a Two-Way SSL connection with client cetificate.

Firstly you need to make a keystore (JKS) containing:

- your private key
- all certificates upwards including the root CA

Maybe using https://keystore-explorer.org/ may help you to understand and verify the content of your keystore.

There are multiple ways to configure the client certificate in SoapUI:

- If you use the global configuration (File - Preferences - SSL Settings), there is only one password to be set. Make sure your keystore password and key password are equal.
- If you use the setup on the project level, you are allowed to enter two passwords.